# How to load json and value out of json in Pig?

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I have a json and value out of json

> 000000,{"000":{"phoneNumber":null,"firstName":"xyz","lastName":"pqr","email":"email@xyz.com","alternatePickup":true,"sendTextNotification":false,"isSendTextNotification":false,"isAlternatePickup":true}}

I'm trying to load this json in pig using elephant bird json loader but unable to do that.
I'm  able to load the following json

> {"000":{"phoneNumber":null,"firstName":"xyz","lastName":"pqr","email":"email@xyz.com","alternatePickup":true,"sendTextNotification":false,"isSendTextNotification":false,"isAlternatePickup":true}}

Using following script -

```
REGISTER json-simple-1.1.1.jar;
REGISTER elephant-bird-pig-4.3.jar;
REGISTER elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.3.jar;

json_data = load 'ek.json' using com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader() AS (json_key: [(phoneNumber:chararray,firstName:chararray,lastName:chararray,email:chararray,alternatePickup:boolean,sendTextNotification:boolean,isSendTextNotification:boolean,isAlternatePickup:boolean)]);

dump json_data;
```

But when I include value out of json

```
json_data = load 'ek.json' using com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader() AS (id:int,json_key: [(phoneNumber:chararray,firstName:chararray,lastName:chararray,email:chararray,alternatePickup:boolean,sendTextNotification:boolean,isSendTextNotification:boolean,isAlternatePickup:boolean)]);
```

it is not working!! Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonLoader` allows loading only of correct json, while your format is actually `CSV`. There are three options for you ordered by incresing complexity:

1. Adjust your input format and make id part of it
2. Load data as CSV (as 2 fields: id and json, then use custom UDF to parse json field into a tuple)
3. Write custom loader that will allow you your original format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin JsonStorage and JsonLoader()

```
a = load 'a.json' using JsonLoader('a0:int,a1:{(a10:int,a11:chararray)},a2:(a20:double,a21:bytearray),a3:[chararray]');
```

In this example data is loaded without a schema; it assumes there is a .pig_schema (produced by JsonStorage) in the input directory.

```
a = load 'a.json' using JsonLoader();
```